# Only one of two nearly-identical .htaccess redirects works

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have these rules at the very top of my .htaccess file.
The second one (client-stories) works as expected, redirecting all requests to `domain.com/site/category/client-stories/` to `domain.com/site/client-stories/`. The first one, `conversations` does not work. I've tried them in the opposite order, with `client-stories` first, and still `client-stories` works, `conversations` does not.

```
Redirect 301 /site/category/conversations/ /site/conversations/
Redirect 301 /site/category/client-stories/ /site/client-stories/
```

[Updated to add:] The .htaccess file in `/site/ continues as follows:

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

#Expires Header
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
AddType image/x-icon .ico
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css M604800
ExpiresDefault M604800
</IfModule>
# WP-AVOID-SLOW Begin
# ETags
FileETag none
# WP-AVOID-SLOW END
```

In addition, there is a root-level `.htaccess`:

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.secondary-domain.com$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secondary-domain.com$
rewriterule ^ "http\:\/\/domain\.tv\/site" [R=301,L] #4f74d1ea4ff18
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.tv$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.tv$
rewriterule ^ "http\:\/\/domain\.tv\/site" [R=301,L] #4f74d152a5dd3

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
rewriterule ^index\.php$ - [L]
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
rewriterule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Is that _all_ the `mod_alias` configuration, or do you have more rules? And no `mod_rewrite` rules toying with it?

Comment: Is this the only .htaccess? If there are more rules in this .htaccess post them here.

Comment: I updated the question, this is the `.htaccess` file within the `/site/` directory. However, your comments have prompted me to realise there's a root level `.htaccess` as well, which I will now check.

Comment: Updated to add the root-level `.htaccess`